# Duplicate Cases while responding through outlook

Tags: case, duplicate-management, email2case, outlook

I Have configured email-to-case. there is one support distribution group. there are three members(A,B,C) in the group and Email-to-Case address. when a customer sends an email to this distribution group Case will be created in SF. and A, B, C also gets an email. When A responds to the customer through outlook using reply all then another case is creating in SF along with reply to a customer. similarly, when B responds to the initial email sent by a customer, the same thing happens, so there are 3 cases of a similar kind. first one by a customer, the second one by A and third one by B, 2 duplicates created. this is happening only when A and B respond through outlook. how to avoid this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is because they're responding directly to the customer email and their email does not yet have a **[Thread ID](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000330749&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) that Salesforce uses to keep emails/replies under one case**.  They're interacting with the email/customer outside of Salesforce and the case.

Salesforce appends an unique thread ID that you can see in Salesforce on the case when you try to respond.

*I'd advise you to change your workflow*. The point of Email-to-case is that the emails go into Salesforce and your end-users don't need to be cc'd on them. **From Salesforce**, on the case, is where your end-users (in your example: A, B, and C) need to respond to the email. This will ensure their email response contains the Thread ID, and that everything stays under the same case.